# Error with convertFromHTML in React Draft Wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using React Draft Wysiwyg to build a rich text editor. I successfully get the html version from below which I am storing in DB

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
        EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(''))

draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))  // this gives the content in html
```

Now I wish to display the html back into editor so it can be edited. I am using below and its giving error. Can someone please point out what I am missing?

```
const contentfromhtml = convertFromHTML(selectedhtmltext);
setEditorState(
                EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(contentfromhtml))
            )
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '{ contentBlocks: ContentBlock[]; entityMap: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
const contentfromhtml: {
    contentBlocks: Draft.Model.ImmutableData.ContentBlock[];
    entityMap: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
        EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray([]))
const contentfromhtml  = convertFromHTML(htmlformat);

EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentfromhtml.contentBlocks, contentfromhtml.entityMap))
```